# How to add a class to an element and remove to the others siblings in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of `li` elements which are a sidebar. I'm looking the way to add a class `active` to the one clicked, and remove that class from the others.

This is my html code:

```
...
<li ng-click="openNav($event)" ng-class="{'active': isActive }">
    ...
</li>
<li ng-click="openNav($event)" ng-class="{'active': isActive }">
    ...
</li>
<li ng-click="openNav($event)" ng-class="{'active': isActive }">
    ...
</li>
```

And this is the code on my controller

```
Test.controller('NavController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.isActive = false;

    $scope.openNav = function($event) {
        //$scope.isActive = true;
    }
})
```

The line `$scope.isActive = false;` removes the class as I need, but I cannot find the way to add the class to the clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the angular way to do it...

```
<li ng-click="openNav(active = 1)" ng-class="{'active': active == 1 }">
<li ng-click="openNav(active = 2)" ng-class="{'active': active == 2 }">
<li ng-click="openNav(active = 3)" ng-class="{'active': active == 3 }">
```

Edit: Be aware, that you should replace `active` with something like `active.nav` so you wont run into issues later.

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple conditions in ng-class

```
<li ng-click="openNav($event)" ng-class="{'active': isActive, 'normal': isNotActive }">
```

Comment: Thanks man I was thinking how to implement it. Never new you can add multiple conditions in ng class

Answer (score 1):

The active propery should refer to every item - think of it like enum - not like boolean
working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/prash/Cp73s/267/

```js
var myapp = angular.module('sampleapp', [ ]);

myapp.controller('samplecontoller', function ($scope) {

  
 $scope.showData = function( ){

 
     $scope.datalists = [
    { "name": "Read about angular"},
    {"name": "Read about knockout"},
    {"name": "Read about backbone"},
    {"name": "Read about jquery"},
    {"name": "Read about javascript"}
    
]
}
 $scope.select= function(item) {
        $scope.selected = item; 
 };
$scope.isActive = function(item) {
        return $scope.selected === item;
 };

      
 
});
```

```css
.paginationclass{
    
margin: 19px 28px;    
}
.paginationclass div{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleapp">
    <div ng-controller="samplecontoller" ng-init="showData()">
        
        
 <ul>
 <li class="paginationclass" ng-repeat="datalist in datalists" ng-click="select(datalist)" ng-class="{active: isActive(datalist)}">
 <div>{{ datalist.name }} </div> 
 </li>
</ul> 
        
    
    
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this more heavy when checking?

Comment: @Akxe more heavy than what?

Comment: I never get this, why to load the content of the `li`s dinamically if I already have on the html?

Comment: @Pablo You could use ng-repeat, so it is more easly managable later, but not nessesary for things like navigation...